# Decide whether a number satisfies an underdetermined equation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, combinatorics

Is it *theoretically possible* to decide, with O(1) space and time complexity, whether a known, positive integer K is a solution of the equation

> [image: K = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i (ai + b) = \mu_1 (a + b) + \mu_2 (2a + b) + \ldots]

where *a* and *b* are fixed, positive integers (neither a multiple of the other), and the *μ<sub>i</sub>* s are *unknown* nonnegative integers, all but a finite number of which (but not all) are zero?  If it is not possible in O(1) space and time, what are the space and time requirements for the best known algorithm?

The only approach to this problem I have found is to enumerate a subset of all possible *K*‌s ahead of time, but of course this requires me to pick upper cut-offs *M* and *N* such that *i ≤ N* and ∀ *μ<sub>i</sub> ≤ M*.  Worse, its space requirement is O(*M<sup>N</sup>*), which is likely to be so huge that no lookup algorithm achieves O(1) retrieval performance on real hardware.  I have a bad feeling that this is actually the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) in disguise, but I'm not certain enough of that to give up yet.

I am trying to get all the way to O(1) in both space and time because I need to know if this can be done in real time, in an embedded environment with barely any headroom in either CPU or RAM.

I do *not* need to know the satisfying set of *μ<sub>i</sub>* values.

**EDIT:** This Python function computes a set object `S` such that `K in S` is true if and only if *K* is one of the solutions to the above equation, given *a*, *b*, and cutoffs *M* and *N* as described above.

```
def compute_set(a, b, M, N):
    ss = [a*i + b for i in xrange(1,N+1)]
    aa = itertools.product(xrange(0,M+1), repeat=N)
    rv = set(map(lambda a: sum(a[i]*ss[i] for i in xrange(N)), aa))
    rv.remove(0)
    return rv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve in two stages.

In stage 1, compute a description of the set {(x, y): x, y in Z and ax + by = K} using standard techniques for handling [Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation). Let g = gcd(a, b); unless g divides K, there are no solutions. Compute g via the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to solve ax' + by' = g as well as compute g; the first solution is (x', y') * K/g. The other solutions are related additively by integer multiples of (-b/g, a/g).

In stage 2, compute a description of the (x, y) solutions that can be achieved via different choices of µ<sub>i</sub>. Since K ≥ 0 we know that y ≥ 1 is a necessary condition. If n is a variable, then x ≥ 0 and y ≥ 1 is a necessary and sufficient condition (set µ<sub>0</sub> = y - 1 and µ<sub>x</sub> = 1 and all other µs to 0).

If n is a parameter, then things are a little stickier. Using the results of stage 1, find the solution (x, y) with x ≥ 0 and y maximum (if no such solution, then K is not feasible). For this solution, check whether x/y ≤ n.

```
def egcd(A, B):
    """Returns a triple (gcd(A, B), s, t) such that s * A + t * B == gcd(A, B)."""
    a, b, s, t, u, v = A, B, 1, 0, 0, 1
    while True:
        assert s * A + t * B == a
        assert u * A + v * B == b
        if not b:
            break
        q, r = divmod(a, b)
        a, b, s, t, u, v = b, r, u, v, s - q * u, t - q * v
    return a, s, t

def solvable(K, a, b):
    g, s, t = egcd(a, b)
    q, r = divmod(K, g)
    if r:
        return False
    x, y = s * q, t * q
    assert a * x + b * y == K
    d = a // g
    q, r = divmod(y, d)
    if r <= 0:
        q -= 1
        r += d
    assert 0 < r <= d
    x, y = x + q * (b // g), r
    assert a * x + b * y == K
    return x >= y
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm not sure what you mean by the distinction between "n is a variable" and "n is a parameter".  It makes me think that I didn't explain myself clearly enough - if I say that I could have replaced n with infinity in the summation and noted an expectation that almost all the &mu;<sub>i</sub> are zero, does that help?

Comment: @Zack A little bit. It's actually not too hard to compute the minimum value of n for which µ_n has to be nonzero.

Comment: @Zack Code added. Note that integer division in Python (//) always rounds down rather than rounding to zero.

Comment: This does not do what I want.  Part of the problem is that there's a bug in my equation: I should have written the sum starting at `i=1`, not `i=0`.  But the other problem is that as best I can tell, your code is determining whether there exist two positive integers `x`, `y` such that `ax + by = K`, but that is a *much larger* set of numbers than the set I want.  I will add some code that enumerates precisely the right set, and correct the equation.

Comment: I think I see where you went off the rails: the equation can be rewritten as `K = (a \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \mu_i) + (b \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i)`, but the values of `x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \mu_i` and `y = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i` are *not independent*; arbitrary positive `x` and `y` will not do.

Comment: @Zack That's the point; all of those were feasible. Anyway, I updated the code slightly for your new equation and tested it against your brute force solution.

Comment: This now *appears* to work, but I don't understand *why* it works, so it's hard to gain confidence in it.  Do you have any sort of a reference you could point me at?  Alternatively, I did say I didn't need to know the `\mu_i` values for the real deal, but if you could make your code generate them anyway, that would help me understand why this is a correct solution.

Comment: @Zack Suppose there exist x ≥ y > 0 such that a * x + b * y = K. If x > y, let µ_1 = y - 1 and µ_{x - (y - 1)} = 1. If x = y, let µ_1 = y. Conversely, given µ_i such that ∑(µ_i * (a * i + b)), derive x = ∑(µ_i * i) and y = ∑µ_i. Since i ≥ 1 and K > 0, x ≥ y > 0. I'm minimizing y subject to the constraints a * x + b * y = K and y > 0 and x and y are integers. Every solution with greater y has lesser x, so it's this one or nothing.

Comment: I found a different formulation of the problem that makes it obvious that your solution is correct, but it took me until now to convince myself that they were really equivalent.  Thank you for your patience and answers to all my follow-up questions.